# Date modulo week in time axis

Tags: date, time, gnuplot, cycle

I have time series data looking like this:

```
20140630 22:40:00 25.5
20140630 22:45:00 25.54

20140630 23:00:00 25.54
20140630 23:05:00 25.6

20140630 23:50:00 25.28
20140630 23:55:00 25.325
20140701 00:00:00 25.34
20140701 00:05:00 25.22
20140701 00:10:00 25.2

20140702 00:25:00 25.1
20140702 00:30:00 25.18
20140702 00:35:00 25.14

20140703 00:40:00 25.14
20140703 00:45:00 25.12
20140703 00:50:00 25.1
```

over many days. I would like to plot my data modulo week, creating overlays similar to the following (but note that I used time in seconds and took it modulo 60*60*24*7): [image: Date Plot]
gnuplot does not recognize day of week in `set timefmt`, otherwise a format string of `"%a %H:%M"` would be perfect for my purposes. My data are pulled from a database and can be preprocessed (currently in Ruby/Rails). Some data points can be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might benefit from the function [`timecolumn()`](http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/demolab/html.php?html=doc/gnuplot-doc/html/timecolumn), which parses a time string from a column according to the set timefmt settings. The result is a time stamp in seconds.

I'd use it in this way:

```
plot 'file.dat' using (timecolumn(1)/60*60*24*7):2
```

assuming you are using something like:

```
set timefmt "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
```

(By the way, I had problems with the space in the date and I resolved using the format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`)

Comment: You must have `using 1:3`. `timecolumn` works fine with spaces, buy those spaces in the datetime are also counted as column delimiters